# Python 3.11 - how to detect socket closed by peer when working with Asyncio Streamers?

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm testing the TCP echo client example script in Python 3.11 Asyncio Streamer official document. It worked as expected, but doesn't seem to detect whether the socket is closed by peer.

The client side code:

```
import socket
import asyncio

async def echo_client(addr,port):
    r,w = await asyncio.open_connection(addr,port)

# send data normally & receive echoed back string
    w.write("hello".encode())
    await w.drain()
    data = await r.read(100)
    print("received: {}".format(data))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

# tell the server side to close socket connection
    w.write("exit".encode())
    await w.drain()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

# the underlying socket is already closed at this point, but
# streamer won't react unless uncommenting following 2 lines:
    # w.close()
    # await w.wait_closed()

# write() only send data to kernel, OK I get that
    res = w.write("hello again".encode())
    print(f"write: {res}")
# but why drain() neither rise except nor return any error ?
    res = await w.drain()
    print(f"drain: {res}")
# read() returned immediately with 0 bytes read, as expected
    data = await r.read(100)
    print("received: {}".format(data))

asyncio.run(echo_client("127.0.0.1",8000))
```

The server side simply echos back what's received from the connection, and will close connection (without echoing back) if received string starts with "`exit`". So in the code above, the connection is closed @line17.

The problem is: why the following `write()` @line26, `drain()` @line29 and `read()` @line32 neither rise any exception, nor return any error message ?

The result is:

```
received: b'hello'
write: None
drain: None
received: b''
```

It'll only rise exception if uncommenting `w.close()` and `w.wait_closed()` so that the Streamer will only know the socket is not available anymore.

Yes I'm aware that I'd never know whether the socket is good or not until I interact with it, and `write()` simply sends data to kernel buffer. but I didn't expect that even `drain()` won't give any meaningful signals about the closed socket.

So the question is: how can I detect whether the underlying socket of Asyncio Streamer is closed by peer, other than checking the return value of `r.read()`?

**[EDIT]**

After some test I've successfully let `read()` throw exception, but the rule is quite weird. The minimal code to trigger exception is:

```
import asyncio

async def echo_client(addr,port):
    r,w = await asyncio.open_connection(addr,port)
    w.write("exit".encode())
    await w.drain()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    # socket is closed by peer at this point

    w.write(b'0')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    w.write(b'0')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    # will rise BrokenPipeError
    await r.read(100)

asyncio.run(echo_client("127.0.0.1",8000))
```

Call to `read()` @line16 will finally rise `BrokenPipeError`, as it supposed to be. The point is:

1. You *MUST* call `write()` at least twice after the socket is closed by peer, and each call must write at least 1 byte of data, so that the Asyncio will finally realize that this socket is not valid anymore.
2. And you must give Asyncio sometime to deal with system error message from the 1st `write()` call, and mark the socket as broken after 2nd `write()` call.
3. For some unknown reason, `write()` will never rise exception, only `read()` and `drain()` (which will rise `ConnectionResetError`).

I must say, this behavior is inconsistent and not satisfying. It make me rethinking whether it's a good idea to adopt Asyncio solution. I guess I'd better stick to low-level Transports & Protocols model, if I keep using Asyncio.

Comment: The `read()` method returns an empty byte array at end of stream. That's the only test there is.

Comment: @user207421: read the [ EDIT ] part in original post. Both `read()` and `drain()` can throw exception, which is supposed to be correct. The problem is that Asyncio is just lagging at handling `write(2)` error.

Comment: `read()` can certainly throw exceptions, but not when reading end of stream. 'Broken pipe' means that you wrote to a connection that the peer had already closed, which is the truth here.

Comment: @user207421 And that's why I'm complaining about the inconsistency of Python Asyncio. The POSIX `read(2)` will not set `errno` to `EPIPE` but `EBADF` so it doesn't make sense that `r.read()` throws `BrokenPipeError` and `w.drain()` throws `ConnectionResetError`. And my biggest complaint is that why `w.drain()` won't throw exception nor return anything that can detect "peer is not reading" on the **first call** after peer closing the socket. Or at least a exception shall be thrown by Asyncio event loop when task yielding control back to event loop after first `w.write()` call.

Answer (score 0):

The tiny comment by user207421 is correct.

In the case of a graceful TCP connection termination, the connection has to be closed on both sides. The initiator closes a connection (a FIN packet is sent from the initiator). It cannot write any more data and this is reported as an EOF condition on the other side (`read` returns 0 bytes). The other side has to close its side as well (a second FIN packet is sent to the initiator).

Please note that a deliberately half-closed connection can exist. One side sends data, then EOF to signalize the end of data, but waits for a reply from the other side before fully terminating the connection. The EOF in this case is not a result of a `.close()`, but there is a special low-level function `socket.shutdown()` and in `asyncio` there is corresponding `.write_eof()`

A TCP client normally communicates with the server using a higher level protocol (e.g. SMTP, HTTP, IMAP, etc.) That protcols govern when each side has to close its connection. In the simple echo server case there is no precise protocol specification, it is probably considered "implied".

---

To explain the "[EDIT]" - to get the error, the data must first reach the server which will respond with a RESET packet, because it has closed the socket. Only when the RESET packet arrives to the client, the application can detect the error condition.

Comment: I'm familiar with socket & select in C so I expect that Streamer would be capable to handle socket closing even just like `Protocols.connection_lost()` and close the socket. Frankly speaking, I'm kinda shocked by the lack of error handling of Asyncio Streamer. And I don't quite understand why can't Asyncio handle EPIPE or SIGPIPE correctly generated from write(2) when calling `drain()`, which can be implemented by adding WRITABLE flag in select() scheme.

Comment: And no I don't think the RESET packet can explain the scheme in [ EDIT ]. I've waited a whole second before calling `write()` and `drain()` on a socket whose peer is no longer reading. The `write(2)` will just return -1 and `errno` set to EPIPE. That's how you can detect a broken pipe when coding socket in C. And there is no consistent way to do that in Asyncio Streamer.

Comment: That's great that you know the TCP/IP internals. You could check with tcpdump or similar. When the client receives the FIN, the read returns empty bytes and the client now knows that the server has closed its socket. The asyncio stream code cannot know if the server did a half-close or a regular close. It cannot declare the connection broken, beacuse it might be a violation of the application protocol, but  NOT of the TCP network protocol.

Comment: I can understand that `read()` will return zero-byte since that's how `read(2)` works, and `read(2)` does not set `errno` to `EPIPE`, only `EBADF`. It's a common approach to call `read(2)` to detect socket closing in C when working with `select()` scheme and I'm comfortable with it. My biggest complaint is that why `drain()` won't throw exception nor return anything that can detect "peer is not reading" on the **first call** after peer closing the socket.

Comment: Please read the docs what is `drain()` doing. It is a flow control method checking sender's data buffer comparing it with high-water and low-water marks. It does not even ensures all data is sent to the network and definitely it does not wait for ACKs. As I wrote, the error occurs when sent data arrive on the other side of the connection and there is no listening socket (remember, there could be a listening-only socket). The OS responds with a RESET and only when that RESET is transmitted back to the sender is the error detected on sender's side. This is long after the `drain` has returned.